# How to send a proper hexadecimal message with node's net module?

Tags: hex

I'm trying to understand TCP communication in node.js. I'm new to this kind of knowledge.
I made net client and I'm trying to send messages to my device, like this:

```
client.write('\xAA\xAA\x02\x65\x01\x00\x10\x13\x0F\x29\x03')
```

and I'm using Terminal by Br@y app to read the received message. I would expect this message to be received as
AA AA 02 65 01 00 1 13 0F 29 03
but instead I see this:
C2 AA C2 AA 02 65 01 00 10 13 0F 29 03
There are some similarities but the above two are not identical. When I try to send any other messages using the above notation, they are always changed but they contain part of what I was trying to send. Can anybody please explain why is that happening?